# use Jquery UI in Dart

Tags: jquery, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to create a simple dialog in Dart and I thought it was easier to use existing javascript libraries.
[Here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) you can find the basic example, basically

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
```

On internet and stackoverflow you can find 1000 examples but none works to me.
I suppose this is the correct way:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
//[...]
var jquery = new js.JsObject(js.context['jQuery']);
var myob = jquery('#dialog').dialog();
```

All I get is this error:

> Breaking on exception: Class 'JsObject' has no instance method 'call'.

Have I misread Dart's documentation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, there are 2 libraries to interop with js : [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) and [package:js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js). *dart:js* has been created after *package:js* and most of the stackoverflow answers use *package:js* and are still valid (it isn't worth to downvote these answers...)

*package:js* provides a simpler Api that comes at the cost of an increase of the js size (because *package:js* uses *dart:mirrors* and *noSuchMethod*).

With *package:js* :

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

main() {
  js.context.$("#dialog").dialog();
}
```

---

With *dart:js* :

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

main() {
  js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['#dialog']).callMethod('dialog');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional note about downvoting. I think I might have downvoted some because I thought they were outdated. I might go and add an answer myself next time I'm stuck browsig SO for answers. :) (I generally don't do that because new answer to old questions don't get much exposure unfortunately)

Comment: I tried the second one and it works BUT I get a warning: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. I'm not sure where to use that though.

Comment: I think this warning comes from the js code inside the _dialog_ plugin.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
context.callMethod(r'$', ['#dialog'])
       .callMethod('dialog', []);
```

Comment: your answer is correct as well. Unfortunately I can't flag both as correct :(

Answer (score 0):

You can need just to be notified on callback. There is quick fix:

```
class CallbackFunction implements Function {
  final Function f;
  CallbackFunction(this.f);
  call() => throw new StateError('There should always been at least 1 parameter'
  '(js this).');
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    Function.apply(f, []);
  }
}

.callMethod("spinner", [new js.JsObject.jsify({
    "stop": new js.JsFunction.withThis(new CallbackFunction(recalc),
    "page": 1,
    "step": 0.1
    })])

void recalc(){
   print("recalcing");
}
```

You can parse invocation argument to read javascript callback arguments. Source: 'package:js/js.dart':line 238 (may change)